# ASA wont pass all traffic

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

I have an ASA I set up for a non profit org which is not passing traffic. Packet tracer gives me mixed results depending on where the traffic is coming from, the two results are that the traffic is being dropped by an ACL and the other that it is a NAT issue. Im sure its something obvious that im missing. I can get to certain sites like youtube and google drive but not others such as dropbox or gmail. They stream live to youtube without issues as well. Im inclining towards it being a problem with traffic getting back in from the outside interface to the inside interface. Here is the current config.

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.0(3)
!
hostname ASANAME
domain-name abcd.org
enable password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted
names
name 172.20.10.1 ASANAME
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan10
 description to INSIDE VLAN
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address ASANAME 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan100
 description to OUTSIDE interface
 nameif OUTSIDE
 security-level 0
 ip address dhcp setroute
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description physical connection to Cablemodem
 switchport access vlan 100
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 description TRON_NET
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 description WF
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 description PR
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 10
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
passwd Vy9tC77pJs8BycTr encrypted
banner motd
banner motd +-+
banner motd | |
banner motd | *** Unauthorized Use or Access Prohibited *** |
banner motd | |
banner motd | For Authorized Official Use Only |
banner motd | You must have explicit permission to access or |
banner motd | configure this device. All activities performed |
banner motd | on this device may be logged, and violations of |
banner motd | this policy may result in disciplinary action, and |
banner motd | may be reported to law enforcement authorities. |
banner motd | |
banner motd | There is no right to privacy on this device. |
banner motd | |
banner motd +-+
banner motd
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EDT -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
dns domain-lookup INSIDE
dns domain-lookup OUTSIDE
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 75.75.75.75
 name-server 8.8.8.8
 domain-name lldm.org
object-group icmp-type DefaultICMP
 description Default ICMP Types permitted
 icmp-object echo-reply
 icmp-object unreachable
 icmp-object time-exceeded
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
 port-object eq ssh
 port-object eq telnet
object-group service DropBox tcp
 port-object eq 17500
 port-object eq 17600
 port-object eq 17603
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service RTMP_Streaming tcp
 description Used to stream to youtube
 port-object eq 1935
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service TeamViewer
 service-object tcp-udp eq www
 service-object tcp eq 5938
 service-object tcp eq www
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1
 service-object tcp-udp eq www
 service-object tcp eq www
 service-object tcp eq https
 service-object tcp eq domain
 service-object udp eq domain
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2
 service-object ip
 service-object tcp-udp eq domain
 service-object tcp-udp eq www
 service-object tcp eq https
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit ip any any log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit udp any any log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq https log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq domain log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit icmp any any echo
access-list ACL_INSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq www log
access-list ACL_INSIDE_IN extended permit ip any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit ip any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit udp any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq www log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq https log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit tcp any any eq domain log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_OUT extended permit icmp any any echo
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_IN extended permit ip any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_IN extended permit udp any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_IN extended permit tcp any any log
access-list ACL_OUTSIDE_IN extended deny tcp any any object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_1 log warnings inactive
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit object-group TCPUDP any any eq domain
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit tcp any any object-group RTMP_Streaming
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit object-group TeamViewer any any
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit tcp any any object-group DropBox
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit ip 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 any log
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit ip any 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 log
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit tcp 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 any log
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit tcp any 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 log
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit udp any 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 log
access-list OUTSIDE_ACL extended permit udp 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 any log
access-list INSIDE_nat_outbound extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0 any
access-list INSIDE_nat_outbound extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2 any 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0
access-list INSIDE_access_in extended permit ip any any
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging timestamp
logging monitor informational
logging buffered informational
logging history warnings
logging asdm informational
mtu INSIDE 1500
mtu OUTSIDE 1500
mtu dmz 1500
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-603.bin
asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (OUTSIDE) 1 interface
nat (INSIDE) 1 172.20.10.0 255.255.255.0
access-group INSIDE_access_in in interface INSIDE
access-group OUTSIDE_ACL in interface OUTSIDE
route OUTSIDE 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 LANCASA 1
route INSIDE 172.168.20.0 255.255.255.0 LANCASA 1
route INSIDE 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 LANCASA 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout uauth 0:05:00 absolute
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL
http server enable
http xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 255.255.255.255 OUTSIDE
http xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 255.255.255.0 INSIDE
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
telnet timeout 5
ssh xxxxxxx xxxxxxx INSIDE
ssh xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx OUTSIDE
ssh timeout 59
ssh version 2
console timeout 0
dhcpd dns 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
dhcpd lease 691200
dhcpd domain abcd.ORG
!
dhcpd address 172.20.10.100-172.20.10.131 INSIDE
dhcpd dns 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76 interface INSIDE
dhcpd lease 1048575 interface INSIDE
dhcpd domain abcd.org interface INSIDE
dhcpd enable INSIDE
!

no threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics
username xxxxxx password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx encrypted privilege 15
!
!
prompt hostname context
Cryptochecksum:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
: end
```

Comment: Can you provide specific examples (ip addresses) of the problems?  Also please post log messages when connections fail.

Comment: there wasn't much in the way of denied in the logs, looks like it was a routing table problem.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, post it in the answer so the question doesn't keep popping up, and so others can learn from it.

Comment: sure, i just had to try a ton of websites first to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started spinning in circles which brought me to the route table...For some reason I had 2 default routes and one static which had a mistyped network and pointed to a routable address.

The first route outlined in red is set via the host name of the ASA which is the default gateway for my Inside network.

The second route outlined in red is a default to the host name of the asa, which is a private IP not routable. So whenever I would hit certain IP's most of the time it was probably hitting that route which would send that traffic back to the INSIDE interface and never get anywhere.

I noticed that my ACL on the INSIDE network was getting alot of hits on its incoming ACL entries but nothing on the OUTSIDE ACL, that sort of tipped me off. Everything is working now.

[image]